# C# Connect via SSH and changing the file content

Tags: c#, .net

I am a C # amateur I am not a professional developer and would like to ask my colleagues for help, I would like to make a C # program that connects to an SSH server. Then, depending on the selected value in combobox, the program downloads the appropriate string and I would like to send it to the ssh server to the specified path path and save the value from the string to the file;)

I tried to rewrite the code but something did not work out and I stopped in my place ;( Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance for your help.

this is my code

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using Renci.SshNet;

namespace FileGenerator
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SshClient sshClient = new SshClient("192.168.1.22", 22, "root", "pass");

            sshClient.ConnectionInfo.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);
            sshClient.Connect();

            ShellStream shellStreamSSH = sshClient.CreateShellStream("vt-100", 80, 60, 800, 600, 65536);

            Thread thread = new Thread(() => recvSSHData(shellStreamSSH));

            thread.Start();

            //I don't know how to get the information if it is connected correctly and change e.g. btnConnect label to Connected.

        }


        public static void recvSSHData(ShellStream shellStreamSSH)
        {

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (shellStreamSSH != null && shellStreamSSH.DataAvailable)
                    {
                        string strData = shellStreamSSH.Read();

                    }


                }
                catch
                {

                }

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
            }


        }


        string data1 = "data1";
        string data2 = "data2";
        string data3 = "data3";
        string check;
        string path = "/home/test01/desktop";
        string filename = "test.txt";
        private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (cmbData.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                check = data1;
                MessageBox.Show(check);
            }
            else if (cmbData.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                check = data2;
                MessageBox.Show(check);
            }
            else if (cmbData.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
                check = data3;
                MessageBox.Show(check);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Choose a value");

            }

        //And now there should be an instruction that sends a string check to the server to path to file replacing its contents

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: What library are you using that gives you an SSH client?

Comment: Library SSH.NET

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I coped with everything but I am on the last step, how to save the contents of string to a file using client scp ??

```csharp
string text= "bal bla bla bla bla"
string path = "@/home/test01/desktop/";
string filename =  "test1.txt"

...

  try
  {
      MemoryStream mStrm = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
      scpClient.Upload(mStrm, path +  filename);


  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
  }
```

I have error:

```
Renci.SshNet.Common.ScpException: scp: error: unexpected filename: 
   w Renci.SshNet.ScpClient.CheckReturnCode(Stream input)
   w Renci.SshNet.ScpClient.UploadFileModeAndName(IChannelSession channel, Stream input, Int64 fileSize, String serverFileName)
   w Renci.SshNet.ScpClient.Upload(Stream source, String path)
   w FileGenerator.Form1.btnSend_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) w C:\Users\backu\source\repos\FileGenerator\FileGenerator\Form1.cs:wiersz 192
```

Comment: It is good: string path = "/home/test01/desktop/";